# Table number not right after using tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, ltablex

I just found that after I used `tabularx`, the table number in my document is not right, shown as follows

[image]

where the first four tables were done using `tabularx` and they are all even numbered, despite the fact that no other tables are there in between, while the tables done using normal `tabularx` are numbered rightly.
The following code is the structure I used

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.85in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in ]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newsavebox{\largestimage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlength{\mylen}
\usepackage{siunitx}   %%package for scientific notation

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\enspace}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}

\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\tablename\enspace}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\mylen}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}

%\captionsetup[table]{aboveskip=0pt}
\captionsetup[table]{belowskip=11pt}

%%%%%tables
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~} %%% bullet in table

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}


\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
hyperref=true,
style=authoryear,firstinits,  
uniquename=false,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false,
mincitenames=1,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=999,
]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     citecolor    = Blue
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{MyCollection.bib}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %%page number
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %no indentation
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{table}[H]
    \footnotesize\keepXColumns
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\itshape}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
    \setlist[itemize]{wide =0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep, before=\vspace{-\baselineskip}, after = \vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c |X |} \hline
    \thead{Title One} & \thead{Title Two} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Things One} &  Content One\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption[Blah Blah]{Blah Blah}
    \label{tab:one}
    \end{table}
    \end{center}
\end{documen}
```

and how it looks like in the report
[image]

Everything is fine apart from the table number.
Any suggestions on how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: A minimal working example is the code that is minimal and has the same issue as described. The code above misses `\documentclass`, the relevant packages and is not compilable

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've added whatever package I used for my thesis, cz It is really long, I am not sure which one is for the table now.

Comment: @ZhifangHu: You're using `ltablex` which is the `longtable` version for `tabularx`. Just put the `\caption` and the `\label` command before `\end{tabularx}`

Answer (score 4):

`ltablex` uses `longtable` in the background in order to merge the features of `tabularx` and breakable tabular environment.

However, `longtable` increases the `table` counter even if there is no `\caption` command.

The `\caption` command should be inside in the `longtable` environment, which is no floating environment then and everything will be alright. Using it outside in the redefined `tabularx` environment the environment will increase `table` and the outer `\caption` will step it again, so the table number steps by 2 and not by one, as expected.

Solution: Use `\caption` within `\begin{tabularx}...\end{tabularx}`, not after it.

The `table` environment around the redefined `tabularx` environment is not really useful, in my point of view. Removing it would make `\caption` outside of `tabularx` impossible any way, so shifting the `\caption` inside of `tabularx` is the best way, other than manipulating the `table` counter

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex} 

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c}

\end{longtable}

The table number is now: \thetable -- although there is no caption command. 


\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c |X |}
    \hline
  \caption[Blah Blah]{Blah Blah}    \label{tab:inside}  % 'Correct' counting should be 2
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

% Now with wrong \caption outside

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c |X |}
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption[Blah Blah]{Blah Blah}    \label{tab:outside} % Now tabularx increases and \caption increases again: counter is 4
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]