# tabularx affecting table numbering

Tags: tables, numbering, tabularx

I have just found that using `tabularx` disrupts normal numbering of tables (please see picture). According to [Tex link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375024/table-number-not-right-after-using-tabularx) this can be due to the `\caption` command being outside of the `tabularx` environment. However, when I rectify this, I get error messages on compilation.

Can someone advise please?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[main=british]{babel}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}%this changes the page geometry i.e. margins left, right, top and bottom
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{titleps,microtype,setspace,amsmath,SIunits,tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell,ltablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library}
\onehalfspacing

\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
        topsep     = 0pt,
        partopsep  = 0pt,
        leftmargin = *,
        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
}}

\keepXColumns

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
    \label{table:comparison of techniques}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
            X
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  % content of `X` column is now centered
            X
            @{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{\textbf{Goal}}& \thead{\textbf{Task}} & \thead{\textbf{Action}} \\
        \midrule
        Evaluate the ease in which users can join projects
        &   Task 1:  Access and account set up
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item   Text.

            Text.
            \item Join the project.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate the ease in learning to map
        &   Task 2:  Learning how to map
        &   Read tutorial   \\
        \addlinespace
        Contribute data
        &   Task 3: Contributing data by classifying maps
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item Begin mapping.
            \item Text.
            Text.
            \item Review maps classified.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate if the user likes using the application and whether they like using it
        & -- & --                   \\
        \bottomrule
        \vspace{-18mm}%needed otherwise the table gets lost between pagebreaks. 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Cognitive walkthrough - evaluation questions}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \centering
    \small
    \hspace*{-18mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ p{30mm} p{80mm} }
        \toprule
        Question & Description \\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        1 & Is the effect of the current action the same as the user's goals \\
        2 & Is the action visible? \\
        3 & Will the user recognise the action as the right one? \\
        4 & Will the user understand the feedback? \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Picture - wrong numbering of tables

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ltablex` enables the `longtable` feature for `tabularx`, so ultimately `tabularx` is now a `longtable`. Move `\caption` inside `\begin{tabularx}` and put a `\endfirsthead` after that, also remove the `table` environment` for this

Comment: note that it is not `tabularx` that does this, if you load the `tabularx` package rather than `ltablex` then you get the correct numbering. `ltablex` has rather a lot of features like this unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer and @David. Your advice works perfectly. One follow up query - by removing the `table` environment, I lose the original text spacing, which makes my table much bigger. How do I preserve the formatting and solve the table numbering issue at the same time?

Answer (score 7):

This is a feature of `ltablex` which turns `tabularx` into `longtable` even if a `longtable` makes no sense in that context, such as inside a `table` environment.

For the example posted you could simply use

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{ltablex}
```

But if you want `ltablex` for other reasons in your real document then it is safe enough to just put the table counter back after the `\caption` so that the `tabularx`/`longtable` increments it to the correct value:

```
   \caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
    \label{table:comparison of techniques}
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}%<<<<<<
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
```