# Wrong enumation of tables (only odd numbers)

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

Example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hhline,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{My Table 1}
\label{tab:mytable1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX} \toprule
a & b & c \\ \midrule
1 & 2 & 3\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{My Table 2}
\label{tab:mytable2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX} \toprule
d & e & f \\ \midrule
4 & 5 & 6\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This code result in this:

[image]

As you can see, the automatic enumeration does not count correctly here. I guess, it counts both \table and \tabularx.

[In this very similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428136/tabularx-affecting-table-numbering) it is stated that the reason is the ltablex package which should be removed. Well, I need it because some of my tables are really long and need to be spread over several pages.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I require:

- long tables
- flexible column widths (the X feature)
- captions and labels

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the package (unforuately) makes tabularx in to longtables so you have to use longtable-ish syntax, remove the outer `table` a

Comment: Probably [xltabular](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) might be what you are up to. It also combines features of both packages: `tabularx` and `longtable` meaning you would have access to `X`-type column with a table continuing on subsequent pages.