# xltabular with caption below table

Tags: tables, floats, xltabular

for my thesis I have several long tables, thus I'm using `xltabular`. I need to add captions below the tables, but this seems to be possible only if I put it in a `table` environment :

```
\begin{table}
\begin{small}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        text & text & text \\ 
        \hline
        text & text & text \\
        \hline
    \end{xltabular} 
\caption{example}
\end{small}
\end{table}
```

This provides the right table output (caption below not above table}, but now the float option doesn't seem to work anymore; the table apprears in the wrong place. I tried adding `[!h]`, but nothing works, except removing the `table` environment which makes my caption disappear when placed below the table.

In other cases, I also have footnotes in the tables. Before, I used `tabularx` and it worked well (except that the numbering of the tables was wrong, that's why I'm using `xltabular` now), but with the `xltabular` environment, the footnotes appear on the wrong page.

Any idea what I can do to solve this issue?

Here is part of my code :

```
\documentclass[openany,ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[main=french,italian, spanish, portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\baretabulars

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}
\begin{small}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        text\footnotemark{} & text & text \\
        \hline
    \end{xltabular} 
\end{small}
\caption{text}
\footnotetext{Cf. ci-dessus \ref{reconstructionmorphologiqueI} pour l'explication de la place de l'accent.}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'd appreciate your help very much.

Comment: `xltabular` is intended to be used when you want the table to split across several pages. Such a table can not be placed inside of a `table` environment.

Comment: Also, `small` is not an environment.

Comment: Side note regarding: "Before, I used tabularx and it worked well (except that the numbering of the tables was wrong, that's why I'm using xltabular now)," This is not because you used `tabularx` but due to the `ltablex` package that you added to the preamble. If you want to use `xltabular`, remove `ltablex. (For an explanation see also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375104/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `xltabular`, place the `\caption` inside of the `xltabular` environment and add a `\\` after the caption. To place the caption below the table (on the last page of the table), add `\endlastfoot` after the `\caption`. In the following MWE, I have also replaced the non-existant `small` environment by the `\small` command. (Make sure, you surround `\small` and the `xltabular` with a set of `{}`.

Side note: As a reader, I would expect a table's caption above as opposed to below a table. This is especially true for tables spanning multiple pages.

```
\documentclass[openany,ngerman]{book}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

{\small
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
    \caption{text} \label{key}\\
    \endlastfoot
        \hline
        text\footnotemark{} & text & text \\
        \hline
    \end{xltabular} 
}
\footnotetext{Cf. ci-dessus \ref{reconstructionmorphologiqueI} pour l'explication de la place de l'accent.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!